# Get and use user's current location efficiently for Route Calculation

Tags: java, android, location-services

I am trying to get the users current location and then the render the route using here-maps sdk with the location of the car provided from the Intent, I have a feeling I can improve it a lot as I have to again and again check for permission to get the last known location of user as below:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Below is the complete java file for reference

```
import static com.sjain.routeplanner.GpsService.current_location;

public class ViewMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = ViewMapActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // permissions request code
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    /**
     * Permissions that need to be explicitly requested from end user.
     */
    private static final String[] REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    // map embedded in the map fragment
    private Map map = null;

    // map fragment embedded in this activity
    private MapFragment mapFragment = null;

    // TextView for displaying the current map scheme
    private TextView textViewResult;

    // MapRoute for this activity
    private static MapRoute mapRoute = null;

    boolean paused = false;
    private MapMarker marker;
    private RouteItem route = null;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    static Location location;

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Double lat = location.getLatitude();
            Double lon = location.getLongitude();
            current_location = lat.toString() + "," + lon.toString();
            marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // available
            if (status == 0x00000000) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enable GPS service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkPermissions();
        intentInfo();
    }

    private void intentInfo() {
        try {

            // getting route details from intent
            String id = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("route_id");
            String name = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("route_name");
            String start_name = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("start_point_name");
            String end_name = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("end_point_name");
            String start_coordinate = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("start_point_coordinate");
            String end_coordinate = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("end_point_coordinate");
            ArrayList<String> waypoints = this.getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("route_waypoints");
            ArrayList<String> waypoint_name = this.getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("waypoint_name");
            route = new RouteItem(name, id, start_name + ";" + start_coordinate, end_name + ";" + end_coordinate, waypoints, waypoint_name);

            // setting route name
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
            String details = "Route: " + name;
            title.setText(details);

            //setting route info
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(route.getStart_point());
            sb.append('\n');
            sb.append(route.getEnd_point());
            sb.append('\n');
            TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
            info.setText(sb);

            String type = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
            // if type is display just display the route
            // if track then display the eta and current status
            if (Objects.equals(type, "track")) {
                String location = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("location");
                track_my_ride(location);
            }
        } catch (Error e) {
            Log.e("ViewMapActivity.class", "intentInfo: ", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops!! Error getting route info..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewRouteActivity.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        paused = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        paused = true;
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        map = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);

        // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                    // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    // Set the map center coordinate to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                    map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(19.152568, 72.855825), Map.Animation.NONE);
                    // Set the map zoom level to the average between min and max (no animation)
                    map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);

                    // create marker to display users current location
                    marker = new MapMarker();
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Location temp_location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(temp_location.getLatitude(), temp_location.getLongitude()));
                    map.addMapObject(marker);
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot initialize MapFragment (" + error + ")");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Checks the dynamically controlled permissions and requests missing permissions from end user.
     */
    protected void checkPermissions() {
        final List<String> missingPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        // check all required dynamic permissions
        for (final String permission : REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS) {
            final int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }
        if (!missingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            // request all missing permissions
            final String[] permissions = missingPermissions
                    .toArray(new String[missingPermissions.size()]);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            final int[] grantResults = new int[REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS.length];
            Arrays.fill(grantResults, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            onRequestPermissionsResult(REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS, REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS,
                    grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                for (int index = permissions.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
                    if (grantResults[index] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // exit the app if one permission is not granted
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Required permission '" + permissions[index]
                                + "' not granted, exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                // all permissions were granted
                initialize();
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, locationListener);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void getDirections(View v) {
        // 1. clear previous results
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        textViewResult.setText("");
        textViewResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (map != null && mapRoute != null) {
            map.removeMapObject(mapRoute);
            mapRoute = null;
        }
        // 2. Initialize RouteManager
        RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager();

        // 3. Select routing options
        RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();

        RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
        routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR);
        routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);
        routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

        //start point
        String[] start_coordinate = route.getStart_point_coordinate().split(",");
        routePlan.addWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(Double.parseDouble(start_coordinate[0]), Double.parseDouble(start_coordinate[1])));
        MapMarker start_marker = new MapMarker();
        start_marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(Double.parseDouble(start_coordinate[0]), Double.parseDouble(start_coordinate[1])));

        // adding waypoints
        ArrayList<String> waypoints = route.getWaypoints();
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.size(); i++) {
            String[] d = waypoints.get(i).split(",");
            routePlan.addWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(Double.parseDouble(d[0]), Double.parseDouble(d[1])));
        }

        //end point
        String[] end_coordinate = route.getEnd_point_coordinate().split(",");
        routePlan.addWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(Double.parseDouble(end_coordinate[0]), Double.parseDouble(end_coordinate[1])));
        MapMarker end_marker = new MapMarker();
        Image destination_image = new Image();
        Image origin_image = new Image();
        try {
            destination_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.destination);
            origin_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.origin);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        end_marker.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(Double.parseDouble(end_coordinate[0]), Double.parseDouble(end_coordinate[1])));
        end_marker.setIcon(destination_image);
        start_marker.setIcon(origin_image);
        map.addMapObject(start_marker);
        map.addMapObject(end_marker);

        // 5. Retrieve Routing information via RouteManagerEventListener
        RouteManager.Error error = routeManager.calculateRoute(routePlan, routeManagerListener);
        if (error != RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Route calculation failed with: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    public void track_my_ride(String location) {
        // 1. clear previous results
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        textViewResult.setText("");
        if (map != null && mapRoute != null) {
            map.removeMapObject(mapRoute);
            mapRoute = null;
        }

        // 2. Initialize RouteManager
        RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager();

        // 3. Select routing options
        RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();

        RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
        routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR);
        routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);
        routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

        GeoCoordinate coordinate;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        }
        Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location1 != null) {
            coordinate = new GeoCoordinate(location1.getLatitude(), location1.getLongitude());
        }
        else {
            // default nesco it park coordinates
            //coordinates taken from here maps
            coordinate = new GeoCoordinate(19.15254,72.85571);
        }
        // 4. Select Waypoints for your routes
        routePlan.addWaypoint(coordinate);

        // supposed to be current or last known location of bus
        String[] bus_coordinate = location.split(",");
        routePlan.addWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(
                Double.parseDouble(bus_coordinate[0]),
                Double.parseDouble(bus_coordinate[1])));

        // 5. Retrieve Routing information via RouteManagerEventListener
        RouteManager.Error error = routeManager.calculateRoute(routePlan, routeManagerListener);
        if (error != RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Route calculation failed with: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    private RouteManager.Listener routeManagerListener = new RouteManager.Listener() {
        public void onCalculateRouteFinished(RouteManager.Error errorCode,
                                             List<RouteResult> result) {

            if (errorCode == RouteManager.Error.NONE && result.get(0).getRoute() != null) {
                // create a map route object and place it on the map
                mapRoute = new MapRoute(result.get(0).getRoute());
                map.addMapObject(mapRoute);

                // Get the bounding box containing the route and zoom in (no animation)
                GeoBoundingBox gbb = result.get(0).getRoute().getBoundingBox();
                map.zoomTo(gbb, Map.Animation.NONE, Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);

                textViewResult.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.route_maneuvers), result.get(0).getRoute().getManeuvers().size()));
            } else {
                textViewResult.setText(
                        String.format("Route calculation failed: %s", errorCode.toString()));
            }
        }

        public void onProgress(int percentage) {
            textViewResult.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.precent_done), percentage));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Usually, the Grace Hopper principle (do not ask permissions; ask forgiveness) is a way to go. Try what you want to do, and if an exception happens, then ask permission. Testing for (dynamically changeable) permission achieves nothing because of TOC-TOU race.

Comment: @vnp Though I already have the permissions as you can see from my checkPermission() method in` onCreate` method bus still I have to keep a check, so there is no way around this I will have to do this everytime I try to get lastknownlocation

Answer (score 1):

*Permissions*
If there is a chance that permissions are withdrawn at runtime, possibly causing Permission related exceptions then I am not sure there is a way around asking for permissions on each query.

**Separation of concerns**
Your activity does a lot of different things. I'd try to pull out the entire Permission Handling as much as possible and put it into it's own class/component. The same I'd suggest for the content of the methods track_my_ride and getDirections - btw you're mixing naming conventions :) - see **Other points#1** but at the very least, stick to one principle.

*Extracting permission handling code*
This is a refactoring task. Basically I see two options (there may be more though):

1. Have a base-activity that contains all the permission handling code (I usually try to avoid creating elaborate hierarchies of Activities, because: Composition over inheritance)
2. Move the permission handling into it's own class and provide an interface for others (such as Activities) to interact with it.

**Other points**

1. Variable naming: I'd recommend using camelCase for variable names as well as methods as per the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
2. UI text: Ui text should be kept in the appropriate language file (strings.xml) and not be hard-coded in one language. This facilitates internationalization and re-use of UI text
3. I'd recommend using Google's FusedLocationProvider as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) this way you'll receive updates to locations in a continuous fashion, as per your requirements (interval, displacement, accuracy etc) you can also use it to request one-time locations

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, but can you add code snippet how am I supposed to put permission handling in its own class.

Comment: @warl0ck exporting permission handling into it's own component is not a small code-snippet :) - but if you grasp the conceptual idea it will be straight forward to write. I updated the answer to elaborate on the concept of externalizing the code for handling permissions.